# FormData not sending appended file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, multipartform-data, form-data

I'm making a Javascript app for file uploading with Drag and Drop support - but I've hit a problem I've been stuck on for days.

It seems that 'dropped' files (in my case via jQuery, `.on('drop', function(e){`) files aren't actually being sent.

I've been browsing answer after answer on StackOverflow - **PLEASE DON'T MARK AS DUPLICATE. THE DUPLICATES DO NOT HELP** - I'm yet to find an aspect which I have not considered in my implementation. It's as if this solution is working for everyone else but me...

Don't believe me? 
**[FIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/nnut2s7f/8/)**

*(Disclaimer: obviously I have modified my solution to not use cross-domain requests, I am using an endpoint I found on Fiddle as a substitute, but it appears to present the same problem I have been experiencing - hopefully it is sufficient as the basis for this example)*

The issue is that the upload completes immediately - apparently it is only sending the text data and not uploading the file itself. Reviewing the request payload I see the data is not present.

[image: Screenshot of request headers. Where the file data is supposed to appear, the header is blank]

**Javascript**

```
function uploadFile(file){
  console.log("uploadFile");
  var form = new FormData();
  form.append('file', file);
  form.append('hello', 'world');
  $.ajax({
    url: "/echo/js/?js=hello%20world!",
    type: "POST",
    data: form,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
      alert("SUCCESS");
    }
  });
}
$(document).ready(function(){

  /* Disable default drag/drop browser behavior. */
  $("html").on('drop', function(e){e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation();});
  $("html").on('dragover', function(e){e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation();});
  $("html").on('dragenter', function(e){e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation();});
  $("html").on('dragleave', function(e){e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation();});

  $(".drop_area").on('drop', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    e.stopPropagation();
    var files = e.originalEvent.target.files || e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
    console.log(files);
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      uploadFile(files[i])
    }
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class='drop_area'>
Drop your file in this div.
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.drop_area {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #ffffff;
  height: 300px;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: You need to check the backend, are the backend receive the file ? Upload may completes immediately because you file is to small, and you do test locally.

Comment: I am testing with a rather large file, a few megabytes at least. I have tested locally (obviously that would be instant since all the files are already available on my computer) - however the Fiddle implementation should at least try to transmit the file. I don't understand why there is no file data between the boundaries - is this a common occurrence? Does Chrome simply omit this information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After seeing the blank request headers in Chrome, and based on the fast upload speed, I had assumed the files were not sending.

However after adding code to my backend endpoint (via `var_dump($_FILES['file']);`), I see the following:

```
array(5) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(14) "two-minute.mp4"
  ["type"]=>
  string(9) "video/mp4"
  ["tmp_name"]=>
  string(36) "/Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phpXfCu0U"
  ["error"]=>
  int(0)
  ["size"]=>
  int(12904619)
}
```

The large `size` attribute appears to indicate quite a lot of data was availible from my upload. It was probably working the whole time. I'll look at this more tomorrow but for the moment the answer may be that:

**"It just looks like it's not working from your browser, but it actually is..."**.

Partial credit to @Alisher Gafurov for convincing me to double-check the backend implementation to verify if the file was indeed not present.

Comment: Thank you for the follow up! I too was completely confused over this since Chrome showed the request was ~130 BYTES in size when I was uploading a file sized in megabytes... After reading this I inspected the serverside and everything was okay.

Answer (score 1):

I was with the same problem, here I needed to update my `php.ini` file to increase the value of the config `upload_max_filesize`.